# c++ delete in binary search tree

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I have a binary search tree consists of nodes like:

```
struct ProductNode
{
    Product data;
    ProductNode* left;
    ProductNode* right;
};
```

and I have a delete function that takes ProductNode pointer parameter:

```
void ProductCategory::deleteandnull(ProductNode * p) 
{
    if(p!=NULL)
    {
        delete p;
        p=NULL;
    }
}
```

I have no problem with deletion methods. The left and right pointers are NULL when a new leaf added but when I use this function I see there is no deletion and this operation does not change the binary search tree. What is that problem?

Comment: i said i have no problem with deletion logic.i am ok with them (one child,two child,childless) i asked why when i use this function there is no deletion.

Comment: er... because the function is wrong :/

Comment: so you say the function hasn't got any problem, but then you say it isn't working. Really, you should clear your mind up before asking questions here :)

Comment: Akın Yılmaz : "there is no deletion". in fact, deletion is correctly done ! check my answer for details

Comment: Post some code how you are going to *use* this. You probably should think about how function arguments are passed in C++.

Comment: How do you know there is no deletion?

Comment: WHy don't you restate your question one more time? I can't even understand the question.... I can handle BST and want to help. With a quick look, you are not modifying anything else but deleting the pointer. In general there are boundary cases to take care of:  what if parent node is null (that is, the node itself is the root)? what if you are deleting a node that's a child of another node (that is, the node is not a leaf)? I can't tell what deleteandnull() is doing exactly, but from the code it just deletes a pointer.

Comment: @CppLearner : no, in fact, it deletes an instance of the structue `ProductNode`.

Comment: @eharvest hmmm yeah, the pointer is to the node (productnode), and you pointed out in your reply: there is no modification. Isn't that the whole issue?

Comment: thereis modification, but in child node not in parent node.... when writing in question code `p = null;` `p` is local variable to the function `deleteandnull`. p is only a copy of `parent.left`, so the value of the pointer `parent.left` (which is outside the function) is not modified when modifying  `p`. only thing is modified is `p` which is local variable of the funtion `deleteandnull`. look for an artile about  local variables an passing variable by pointer or reference fo a complete explication and examples...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this instead :

```
void ProductCategory::deleteRightChild(ProductNode * p) 
{
    if(p->right!=NULL)
    {
        delete p->right;
        p->right = NULL;
    }
}
```

write an equivalent fonction for left  child.

your function does not work because you dont change the content of the parent node. it still has the adress of the deleted node so (if this content was realllocated elsewhere and changed) it can access to it... !

but the memory is really deallocated.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: This answer was based on the assumption that the OP was concluding "there is no deletion" because he was expecting to see a NULL pointer in the calling location. If that is not the case he will need to clarify what is leading to that conclusion. As is there is no reason to think the OP's code is not deleting whatever p points to.

`p` is passed by value into the `deleteandnull` function. Therefore only a local copy of the pointer is set to `NULL`. Assuming you have code like this somewhere:

```
ProductNode *ptr = // Somehow initialize to the parent of the node to delete
.
.
deleteandnull(ptr->left);
```

You need to add this after the call to `deletandnull`

```
ptr->left = NULL;
```

Note that it is not necessary to test for NULL before calling `delete`. It will do so itself. And since `p` in `deleteandnull` is a local, there is no point to setting it to `NULL`. So the whole code might as well be reduced to:

```
ProductNode *ptr = // Somehow initialize to the parent of the node to delete
.
.
delete ptr->left;
ptr->left = NULL;
```

All that said, in modern C++ you should not be using bare pointers, `new` and `delete`. Prefer to use smart pointers, for instance as in the Boost library.

Comment: thanks bro but it is still not deleting even if i used delete p; p=NULL; instead of deleteandnull function.i use this deletion operations in a function deletespecified(paramaters) may it be because of this function or because of some & symbol?

Answer (score 1):

```
   Procedure :
   1. At first locate the node to be deleted.

   2. If the node is a leaf node :
   i. If the node is left child of the parent , make null the left pointer of its parent node and free the space for the node.
   ii. If the node is right child of the parent , make null the right pointer of its parent node and free the space for the node.

   3. If the node has one child
    i. If the node to be deleted is a left chile of its parent , then make link between the left pointer of its parent node and the child node to be deleted. Then delete the node.
    ii.If the node to be deleted is a right child of its parent , then make link between the right pointer of its parent node and the child node to be deleted. Then delete the node.

   4. If the node to be deleted has two child :
     i. Locate the node with maximum value from the left sub-tree of  the node to be deleted.
     ii. Replace the node value to be deleted by the node found in step 4(i)

   5. Now we get updated output
```

### C++ implementation :

```
    node* Delete(node *root, int data)
    {
      if(root == NULL) return root;

      else if(data < root->data) root->left = Delete(root->left,data);

      else if (data > root->data) root->right = Delete(root->right,data);

      else
      {
       ///Case 1:  No child
      if(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)
      {
        delete root;
        root = NULL;
      }

      ///Case 2: One child
      else if(root->left == NULL)
      {
        struct node *temp = root;
        root= root->right;
        delete temp;
      }

      else if(root->right == NULL)
      {
        struct node *temp = root;
        root = root->left;
        delete temp;
      }

      ///case 3: 2 children
       else
       {
         node *temp = FindMin(root->right);
         root->data = temp->data;
         root->right = Delete(root->right,temp->data);
       }
     }
    return root;  
}
```

Comment: please properly format your text as text and your code as code.

Comment: I already  properly formatted my code. Please Focus on code not the format. If you find wrong , you will inform me.

Comment: @  Marcus Müller please check my answer.